# Google Sheets App Script throwing an exception

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My Google App Script associated with my Google Sheets document includes the following lines (in a onEdit(e) trigger function):

```
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet.getRange(3, 1, rowIndex, 1).uncheck();
```

Where rowIndex is an integer value (in my example it happens to be a 8). All cells in the range are checkbox cells.

When I trigger this I get a Failed execution and the following log output:

```
Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
           at onEdit(Code:59:13)
```

I have checked the Google documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns and I could have sworn I have it right.

Why is the code interpreting a String in the first parameter when it is clearly a hard coded integer number?

Comment: I think that the reason for your current issue is due to that Class Spreadsheet has only a method of [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)). In this case, please use Class Sheet. In your showing script, pleaes modify `let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` to `let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` or `let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("### sheet name ###");`.